# A query that will search for the highest numeric value in a table where the column has an alphanumeric sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (XID) that contains a varchar(20) sequence in the following format:  xxxzzzzzz Where X is any letter or a dash and zzzzz is a number.

I want to write a query that will strip the xxx and evaluate and return which is the highest number in the table column.

For example:

```
aaa1234
bac8123
g-2391
```

After, I would get the result of 8123

Thanks!

Comment: Reasonable question.  Not worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit painful in SQL Server, but possible.  Here is one method that assumes that only digits appear after the first digit (which you actually specify as being the case):

```
select max(cast(stuff(col, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', col) - 1, '') as float))
from t;
```

Note:  if the last four characters are always the number you are looking for, this is probably easier to do with `right()`:

```
select max(right(col, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks all, for the quick help.  Very appreciated!  Except the minus one without a comment.  I'd thank you too if there was a comment, though.

Answer (score 1):

Using Numbers table

```
    declare @string varchar(max)
    set @string='abc1234'

    select top 1 substring(@string,n,len(@string))
    from
    numbers
    where n<=len(@string)
    and isnumeric(substring(@string,n,1))=1
    order by n
```

**Output:1234**

Answer (score 1):

Using `PATINDEX` you can achieve it, like this -

```
DECLARE @test table
  (
     id    INT,
     player varchar(100)
  )

INSERT @test
VALUES (1,'aaa1234'),
       (2,'bac8123'),
       (3,'g-2391')

SELECT
    MAX(CONVERT(INT, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(player, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', player), LEN(player)))))
FROM @test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Select MAX(RIGHT(XID,17))
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this method

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp
(
  XID VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #Tmp(XID)
VALUES ('aaa1234'), ('bac8123'), ('g-2391') 

SELECT MAX(RIGHT(XID, LEN(XID) - 3))
FROM #Tmp
```